# my browser registers the service worker and caches the urls but it doesn't work offline?

Tags: caching, service-worker

This registers and works perfectly fine online. But when the server is turned off, and when the page is refreshed, the registered serviceworker no longer shows up in the console and no caches in the cache storage.

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator){
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js").then(function(registration){
    console.log("service worker reg", registration.scope)
}).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error:", error);
    })
}
```

in sw.js

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/index.html'
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
       return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
     })
 );
 //event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're properly adding your file to cache, but you're missing returning your cached file on request.

Your `sw.js` should also have following code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

It's from [Introduction to service workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/).

Morover, you should rather cache `/` instead of `/index.html` as usually, you don't hit index.html file directly.

Your service worker doesn't show any console.log when offline, because you don't have any `activate` code. [This article - offline cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/) is very useful to understand details.

Comment: You are right. I noticed that I was missing the fetch code. Although,  my chrome browser is up to date, this cache works offline on canary and not on chrome.

Comment: That's strange. Chrome delivered Cache API in version 46 - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/updates-to-cache-api. Which version exactly do you have? Is CacheStorage object present in console.log in test - https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/globalapis/?

Comment: chrome 51. I was using node as a server and it was not working well with chrome browser.